# Controlling NMOS

Tags: batteries, mosfet, ldo, nmos, voltage-detector

Can I control a NMOS (don't look the reference in the schematic) to shutdown a LDO with a voltage detector like so ? Or is there missing something?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffcN0p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
**EDIT :**
 Other version proposed in the comments because the one above is not going to work :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2few1py.png)</sup>

Comment: Your NMOS is configured as a source-follower and you're trying to high-side switch the supply-line, so no that won't work. An NMOS in that configuration needs a voltage on its gate a few volts higher than what you're trying to switch. That configuration might work with a PMOS and a voltage detector with an inverted output.

Comment: Mmh.. Thanks ! I'll do it with a PMOS and a single inverter !

Comment: Put the FET in the negative wire between the voltage detector and regulator.

Comment: Just use a 2.5V LDO regulator with an enable input.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I thought about it, but is this really going to shut down my system with a floating ground ?

Comment: @Finbarr Yes but I need it to be through hole with a very low quiescent current... And it is quiet nonexistent..

Comment: @JohnD Thank you but it has to be **through hole** and not surface mount.

Comment: MCP1826 no good? Available in a 5 pin TO-220 package for 20th century applications :)

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks, I found it and I first wanted to use it, but 120µA quiescent current is half the consumption of my system... :/

Comment: "is this really going to shut down my system with a floating ground?" depends on the rest of your circuit. A portable device with no other connections to the same supply as the charger would be fine. A device that eg. charges from from a USB port and also communicates over it might not (since the charger and communication circuits share a common ground).

Comment: @BruceAbbott No is just a simple LDO powering 2 modules for a total consumption of 0.3mA and I just have to shutdown the system when the lithium battery reaches 3V.